# What is Sandboxed_process0 and why do i have so many instances of it listed in the memory usage for my app

Tags: android, memory

When I look at my app's memory usage on my device, there are approximately 30 entries of Sandboxed_process0 that appear under the "details" section. I was running/stopping my app from android studio quite a few times on my physical device as I was working on my app a few hours before (in case that's relevant). Firstly, I'm wondering what these processes are and secondly whether or not I should be concerned about them (i.e. are they an obvious indication of me leaking some sort of resource, or doing something wrong).

[image: sample of about 30 Sanboxed_process0 entries]

Comment: Did you found answer to your question? Got similar problem

Comment: I never found the answer to this, but I haven't noticed it impacting my app's performance (could totally be wrong). Do you only see the long list of sanboxed process 0s in development builds of the app or do you see it in production as well?

Comment: Nope, just development builds, production are fine

Comment: same with me, while I'm still curious what the answer is, i didn't pursue it further cause it wasn't an issue in production

Comment: I got bunch of these after adding admob ads to my app.

Comment: Passing along, Hope this helps! https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/65362/what-does-sandboxing-mean-for-chrome-os/65366#65366