# App memory usage shows multiple instances of sandboxed_process0

Tags: java, android

I checked my app in the settings on my phone and I notice that memory usage has a lot of instances called sandboxed_process0.

**What does this mean?**

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is Sandboxed_process0 and why do i have so many instances of it listed in the memory usage for my app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46985635/2985643), though no answer was accepted for that question.